# print statement for a 'read' file overwrites file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Relatively new to python, but am baffled by the fact that the following code OVERWRITES a file specifically set to read and not write:

```
for file in file_args:
    print("searching " + file + "...")
    with fileinput.input(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            from_match = re.search("^From:.*(" + args.text[0] + ").*", line)
            subj_match = re.search("^Subject:.*(" + args.text[0] + ").*", line)

            if from_match or subj_match:
                print("\n" + "-" * 75 + "\n", file = None)
                print("found \"" + args.text[0] + "\" in " + file + "...\n", file = None)
```

I understood that `fileinput.input(file, 'r')` should ONLY allow reading from the source file. Instead, the print statements are replacing the file's existing content, even though they also specify output to be `sys.stdout` (`file = None`).

Comment: Make a [mre]. From a quick look, I don't see anything that would write to any file at all. Maybe the problem isn't where you think it is, for example, maybe you did something like `sys.stdout = file_args[0]` somewhere else in the script. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You can [edit].

Comment: plus a bunch of this code, like the `re.search`, seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: Based on Mikael's answer, [here's an MRE if you want to use it](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/62f662ff17cedd0d4ca992fb7d9e6223)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fileinput` is special. I've never actually seen it used so this was a first for me. It seems to me that you might not even really want this, and perhaps you are looking for just a plain `open(...)` instead.

Your error lies in the not using named arguments. Checking the `help(fileinput.input)` we find the positional arguments are not what you intended:

> ```py
> input(files=None, inplace=False, backup='', *, mode='r', openhook=None, encoding=None, errors=None)
> ```
>
> Return an instance of the FileInput class, which can be iterated.
>
> The parameters are passed to the constructor of the FileInput class.
> The returned instance, in addition to being an iterator,
> keeps global state for the functions of this module,.

You have effectively specified `inplace='r'`, and this non-empty string will be evaluated as `True`. A good editor would hopefully given you a warning about this type difference.

This special feature means that, regardless of the returned file object `f`, all printouts to stdout inside the `with` block is redirected to replace the file (I'm a bit stumped as to how this is actually achieved, but this does seem to be what is happening here. Very unusual library)

You want to use `fileinput.input(files=..., mode='r')`, or, as it is the default already, leave out `mode` completely.

Comment: *"I'm a bit stumped as to how this is actually achieved"* -- See docs: [`FileInput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput): *"if ... inplace=True is passed ..., the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file"*

Comment: *"Very unusual library"* -- It's like that in order to let you replace tools like `perl`, `sed`, etc, which automatically iterate over lines from input file. `sed` has an "inplace" option that's equivalent to this.

Comment: Excellent. Clearly correct answer to an error just obscure enough for me to misunderstand it. Thanks.